# how can I extend a react-bootstrap component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I want to extend the react-bootstrap component and modify some of the prototype to achive my component.Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class myPagination extends Pagination {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  }

  render() {
     return <div>test</div>;
  }
```

}

But here is a error:`Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`
Maybe the Pagination component is created by `React.createClass` so I can't extends the component?
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you show the entire stack trace?

Comment: As a side note, the constructor is redundant. Unless you need to add your own code, the `super` call will happen automatically

Comment: I get no error running this code, you can see it [here](https://jspm-test-tyrsius.c9users.io/) (for a while)

Comment: which version of react-bootstrap do you use?

Comment: which version of react-bootstrap do you use?